# If condition inside preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to add comment inside a replaced text only if condition is true.

This is the basic code I work with.

```
<?php
$keepcomments="yes"; //yes or no
$str="abcdefgh";
$str = preg_replace("~abcd~", 'dcba "if($keepcomments=="yes"){ echo"-- some comments here --"} ', $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

I tried with :

```
if ($keepcomments=="yes"){ 
$str = $str."<-- some comments here -->";
}
```

The result is :

```
dcbaefgh-- some comments here --
```

But I have to `preg_replace` in more lines, problem is when I do that, all the comments are appearing at the end of result string.

```
dcbaefgh
dcbaefgh
dcbaefgh
-- some comments here --
-- some comments here --
-- some comments here --
```

and I don't know how to use `preg_replace_callback()` in this case.

Any help would be appreciated.

## EDIT

When the string is "abcdefgh", i want to replace "abcd" in that string with "dcba". at the same time, if `$keepcomments` is yes, then i want to add a comment at the end of that string.
and then i want to duplicate same code in few more lines. 
Expected output is :

```
dcbaefgh-- some comments here --
dcbaefgh-- some comments here --
dcbaefgh-- some comments here --
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: abcdefgh -- some comments here --
abcdefgh -- some comments here --
abcdefgh -- some comments here --

Comment: Your matching pattern only covers `'abcd'` so at best it would produce `'abcd-- comment here--'`; what exactly are you trying to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a callback function:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("~(abcd)(.*)~", function($match) use ($keepcomments) {
    $r = strrev($match[1]) . $match[2];

    if ($keepcomments == 'yes') {
        return $r . '-- some comments here --';
    } else {
        return $r;
    }
}, $str);
```

Comment: It gives me output like this => -- some comments here --efgh

Comment: @MuhammedAslamC It's not clear what you want? Should the comment only appear at the end of the line, or ... ?

Comment: dcbaefgh -- some comments here -- 
dcbaefgh -- some comments here -- 
dcbaefgh -- some comments here --

i need to output like this :)

Comment: and now your code gives me output => abcd-- some comments here --efgh

Comment: @MuhammedAslamC I know what the output should be like, but I'm asking why that is ... should it match `'abcdefgh` completely or just `'abcd` ` followed by zero or more characters ... I can't tell.

Comment: @MuhammedAslamC I've updated the answer with what I think is the right approach ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!  i had to change something- and i don't know how it worked ;)

$str = preg_replace_callback("~(replace-string-here)(.*)~", function($match) use ($keepcomments) {
    if ($keepcomments == 'yes') {
        return  'string -- comments -- ';
    } else {
        return 'string';
    }
}, $str);

Answer (score 0):

```
$str=array("abcdefgh","dfgvdfg","rgerhg");

foreach($str as &$row)
{
if ($keepcomments=="yes"){ 
$row= $row."<-- some comments here -->";


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer from [jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack) did the trick : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22777242/1940720

i had to change something. i submit the final answer here, maybe it will help someone.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("~(replace-string-here)(.*)~", function($match) use ($keepcomments) {
    if ($keepcomments == 'yes') {
        return  'string -- comments -- ';
    } else {
        return 'string';
    }
}, $str);
```